# How to Successfully open a SWT jar file in Terminal

Tags: java, jar, terminal, swt, osx-mavericks

When I've tried to open a jar file in terminal (OS X 64 bit), I got the next message :

What should I do in order to open the file?

software1 bktomer$ java -jar MusicTunes.jar

***WARNING: Display must be created on main thread due to Cocoa restrictions.

Exception in thread "main" org.eclipse.swt.SWTException: Invalid thread access

```
at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.error(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.createDisplay(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.create(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Device.<init>(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.<init>(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.<init>(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.getDefault(Unknown Source)
at il.ac.tau.cs.sw1.musictunes.ui.GraphicalMusicTunesViewer.createShell(GraphicalMusicTunesViewer.java:63)
at il.ac.tau.cs.sw1.musictunes.ui.GraphicalMusicTunesViewer.show(GraphicalMusicTunesViewer.java:55)
at il.ac.tau.cs.sw1.musictunes.ui.GraphicalMusicTunesViewer.showViewer(GraphicalMusicTunesViewer.java:38)
at il.ac.tau.cs.sw1.musictunes.ui.GraphicalMusicTunesViewer.main(GraphicalMusicTunesViewer.java:33)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must specify the `-XstartOnFirstThread` option when running an SWT program on OS X:

```
java -XstartOnFirstThread -jar MusicTunes.jar
```